# Javascript interpreters in multiple threads

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading

Situation: i have C# code and Nil.JS javascript interpreter inside it. Instances of js engine may be working in different threads. I need to create a variable in one thread and read it from another.

I know something like this works for Lua (you can delete information about table's parent for example, and it will be visible in another thread), but i don't have any idea how to make for javascript. Are there any ways of doing it?